# Adding view/layouts in already inflated hierarchy in runtime?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

I wonder if it is bad practice to add view into view hierarchy in runtime into already inflated view.
Lets consider my example. I have following Activity class hierarchy

1. Base Activity - some base activity that include basic configuration for lifecycle methods , without inflating layout(setContentView).
2. SingleFramgentActivity it has setContenview method in `onCreate` method. Layout for this activity looks following

c

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:orientation="vertical">

    </FrameLayout
    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/stub_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/progress_bar_buttons"
        android:layout="@layout/inflate_stub_progressbar_bg"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

There are several problems here.
As you can see here, there is one fragment container `FrameLayout` for holding current fragment as far as it is `SingleFragmentActivity`.

What I need to do is to add toolbar into my layout and should be present on all fragment inside this activity.
My layout in this case have to look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:orientation="vertical">

    </FrameLayout>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/include_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"/>
    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/stub_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/progress_bar_buttons"
        android:layout="@layout/inflate_stub_progressbar_bg"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

There are several problems here.
1. I have already inflated layout in my `SingleFramgentActivity` class. So I only have way to add to already inflated hierarchy, getting root view and calling `addView` method. If so please see next question.
2. I need only to add some view, I need to add layout file to view hierarchy BETWEEN two already existent views. FrameLayout and ViewStub because of Z placing of view in FrameLayout.

There several solutions for this problem
1. Include toolbar in each fragment where I need it (in all fragments inside activity) It seems not the best way to do , because of code duplication. (Don't repeat yourself rule).
2. Use some basic ToolbarFragment class and also in this case I have to add all required views by inherited fragments in runtime.
3. Use some Decorator class ToolbarActivity and as I have described above to add into already inflated view hierarchy.
4. Use layout the same as for SingleFramgentActivity but to put there toolbar include tag and rename class into SingleToolbarFragmentActivity. Seems that Single Responsibility Principle has been just broken. And what If need only toolbar without fragment container or vice versa.

So I need advice what is the best way to do this. Is not bad practice about performance ?
Please suggest what is better to use in this case not to cause performance issues and keep code as readable as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no performance problem about adding views at runtime if you are not adding them one by one, or changing its layout bounds or, what is the same, calling multiple times to `requestLayout/invalidate`. Anything than that should not cause any performance problem.

Given that, what I usually do in your case is create a lets call it `BaseActivity` with some methods that can be extended like `hasToolbar():boolean` and in the moment of the creation of this activity I inflate what is needed and add it to the view. That is one approach, but any of those you mention can work without a performance problem since inflating a single layout is not so time consuming (like happens in ListViews for example).